# Program is to enter values in one spot then drag over a csv file in another spot, functions to parse and display filename/path

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I am writing a program to enter values in one spot on the GUI and drag a csv file over to another spot. I seem to be having issues calling the functions to do what they are supposed to do. One function is supposed to display the filename to the user. the second parses the filename but is linked to the first function. The 3rd function prints the full path to developer for future use. Here is my code. Any help or advice is appreciated.

```
import csv
from math import *
from pathlib import Path
import statistics
import tkinter
from tkinterdnd2 import *

root = TkinterDnD.Tk()
root.title('Pathfinder')
Canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, bg="white", height=400, width=600)
Canvas.pack()


user_values = tkinter.StringVar()
Instructions1 = tkinter.Label(root, text='Enter Values:')
Instructions1.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
Canvas.create_window(100, 25, window=Instructions1)
entry1 = tkinter.Entry(textvariable=user_values)
Canvas.create_window(100, 50, window=entry1)


def drop_inside_entry_box(self, event):
    file_paths = self.parse_drop_files(event.data)
    current_entry_box_items = set(self.file_names_entry_box.get(0, "end"))
    for file_path in file_paths:
        if file_path.endswith(".csv"):
            path_object = Path(file_path)
            file_name = path_object.name
            if file_name not in current_entry_box_items:
                self.file_names_entry_box.insert("end", file_name)
                self.path_map[file_name] = file_path


def parse_drop_files(self, filename):
    size = len(filename)
    res = []  # list of file paths
    name = ""
    idx = 0
    while idx < size:
        if filename[idx] == "{":
            j = idx + 1
            while filename[j] != "}":
                name += filename[j]
                j += 1
            res.append(name)
            name = ""
            idx = j
        elif filename[idx] == " " and name != "":
            res.append(name)
            name = ""
        elif filename[idx] != " ":
            name += filename[idx]
        idx += 1
    if name != "":
        res.append(name)
    return res

def drop(event):
    var.set(event.data)
    stringvar = str(event.data)
    print (stringvar)

var = tkinter.StringVar()
e_box = tkinter.Entry(textvar=var, width=60)
e_box.place(x=150, y=90, width=380, height=20)
e_box.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)

e_box.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', drop_inside_entry_box) # Here is where the error starts
e_box.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', parse_drop_files())
e_box.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', drop)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: REMEMBER that `e_box.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', parse_drop_files())` does NOT pass the function to bind.  Instead, it immediately CALLS the function and passes its return to `bind`.  Remove that `()`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just made it one big function:

```
def drop(event):
    var.set(event.data)
    stringvar = str(event.data) 
    size = len(stringvar)
    res = []  # list of file paths
    name = ""
    idx = 0
    while idx < size:
        if stringvar[idx] == "{":
            j = idx + 1
            while stringvar[j] != "}":
                name += stringvar[j]
                j += 1
            res.append(name)
            name = ""
            idx = j
        elif stringvar[idx] == " " and name != "":
            res.append(name)
            name = ""
        elif stringvar[idx] != " ":
            name += stringvar[idx]
        idx += 1
    if name != "":
        res.append(name)
    file_paths = res
    current_e_box_item = set(e_box.get())
    for file_path in file_paths:
        if file_path.endswith(".XLS"):
            path_object = Path(file_path)
            file_name = path_object.name
            if file_name not in current_e_box_item:
                e_box.insert("end", file_name)
                e_box.delete(0,last=size)
    print(file_name)
    print (res)
    print(file_path)
    print(path_object)
    print(stringvar)
```